# Installing JBoss Tools 4.0 in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-tools

I have downloaded the latest version of JBoss tools. But while adding it to eclipse it shows the following error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Seam Tools 3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0347-B156
(org.jboss.tools.seam.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0347-B156)            
Missing requirement: JBoss Tools Common Core 3.5.2.Final-v20140302-2358-B158  
(org.jboss.tools.common.core 3.5.2.Final-v20140302-2358-B158)
```

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install *stable version* JBoss Tools for **Eclipse Juno** is to download [Eclipse Java IDE for Java EE Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2) and then install JBoss Tools from [stable update site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/juno/).

Latest *development version* of JBoss Tools is 4.2.0.CR1-v20140914-0645-B242 is targeting **Eclipse Luna SR1** ([update site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/luna/)).

Latest *stable version* of JBoss Tools is 4.1.2.Final-v20140318-2026-B706 is for **Eclipse Kepler** ([update site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/)).